# Return "none" string where no results exist

Tags: php, html-table

I have a simple table, that echos results of a query, and a bit of PHP that alternates the colour of the rows in the table (could not use CSS3 as I need it to work with IE8) and what I have, works. However, in some cases there aren't any records returned. What is the best way to amend the code, so that if there aren't any records to display, it just says "none". Or is this possible via the mysql query instead.....

```
<?php $count = 0; do { ?>
      <tr>
      <?php $count++;?>
        <td colspan = "5" class="<?php echo (($count % 2) == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd'; ?>">
            <?php echo $row_RecordSet1['result']; ?>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <?php } while ($row_RecordSet1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordSet1)); ?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to stick with your coding style, I guess this is how I would do it...

```
<?php $count = 0; ?>
<?php while ($row_RecordSet1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordSet1)) { ?>
    <?php $count++;?>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5" class="<?php echo (($count % 2) == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd'; ?>"><?php echo $row_RecordSet1['result']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php if ($count == 0) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">No results found.</td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: hi crush, thanks for the reply. I tried what you suggested (sorry about my php i'm learning) but although it works (I changed the recordset name to check), where there are results I only see one row returned.....

Comment: Then `$RecordSet1` only contains one record.

Comment: @mdemetri2 I'm sorry man, but if there are more than 2 rows returned by whatever query you assigned to `$RecordSet1` then they will be shown with this script. Tested, and affirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'd suggest you use a `while` loop, you could still maintain your `$count` variable.

```
$count = 0;
while($row_RecordSet1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordSet1)){
    //this way, if the recordset is empty -- the loop will never run
    ++$count;
    //your normal processing continues here
}
if($count === 0){
    //there was no content or result from the database
    echo '<tr><td>None</td></tr>';
}
```

I believe that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before displaying your results, you can check the number of rows with [mysql_num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)(BTW , read carefully the warning in red about mysql extension !)

```
if(mysql_num_rows($RecordSet1) == 0) {//no results
   //display none
} else {
   //display your results
}
```

Comment: Hi, so I have ended up with: </tr> <?php if (mysql_num_rows($RecordSet1) == 0) { echo "No Records"; } else $count = 0; do { ?> <tr> <?php $count++;?> <td colspan = "5" class="<?php echo (($count % 2) == 0) ? 'even' : 'odd'; ?>"><?php echo $row_RecordSet1['result']; ?></td> </tr> <?php } while ($row_RecordSet1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($RecordSet1)); ?> <tr>      which works, however it is displaying the "No Records" at the top of my page and not in the row I want.....any ideas on placement of this code.....appreciated!!